# Expected value conditioned on subset of domain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I have a random variable $X$ with pdf $f(\cdot)$ and support $[0, b]$. As part of some results I am generating, I am left with the integral $$\int_a^b x f(x) \, dx$$ where $0<a<b.$ I am wondering how to think about this integral - can this be expressed $E[X\mid X>a]$ or something like this? Seems like a straightforward question I know but I couldn’t think of the right search terms to use. I’d welcome a link to another post asking the same thing if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost :)
$$
\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>a]
 = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[X>a]} \int_a^b xf(x)\,dx
 = \frac{\int_a^b xf(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}
$$

Comment: Oh makes sense! So I guess it could be expressed $(1-F(a))E[X|X>a]$ if $F$ is the CDF. Can you explain the first equality?

Comment: @jwil yes, $$\mathbb{P}[X>a] = \int_a^b f(x) dx.$$

Comment: I was referring to your first statement where you introduce $\mathbb{P}[X>a]$, but I realized now that’s just the definition of conditional probability. Thanks a bunch! Perhaps more than math help I just need some sleep :)

Comment: @jwil good night :)

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the edit, definitely looks better

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is any subset of $(a,b),$ then you have
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X\in S\mid X>a) = \frac{\Pr(X\in S\ \&\ X>a)}{\Pr(X>a)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(X\in S)}{\Pr(X>a)} = \frac{\int_S f(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b f(x)\, dx}.
\end{align}
Therefore the conditional probability density of $X$ given that $X>a$ is
$$
f_{X\,\mid\,X\,>\,a}(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\int_a^b f(u)\,du}.
$$
So you integrate $x$ times that to get the conditional expected value.